# Quais erros que disparam o catch?

Tags: php, exceção, try-catch

Em um teste similar a [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18081677/php-notice-undefined-index-although-using-try-catch), fiquei em duvida de quais os erros que geram a `Exception`.

Pesquisando eu só encontrei explicações do uso do `try`, `catch`, e algumas referencias de que isto iria depender da configuração do `php_ini`.

Bem, quais os erros de geram `Exception`?

Comment: Em PHP isso é realmente confuso. Mas não vai dar pra listar todos os erros numa resposta, são muitos casos. Como regra geral, quando você usa objetos nativos do PHP, é grande a chance de um método produzir uma exceção e não um erro. E é possível configurar o PHP para (quase) sempre gerar exceções em vez de erros. Aposto que logo alguém explica isso em detalhes numa resposta :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que faz o fluxo do programa entrar em um `catch` é o lançamento de um [`throw`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). Quais são os `throws` que existem em sua aplicação? Quais são os que estão nas bibliotecas que você está usando? Sejam elas pertencentes ao padrão do PHP ou adicionais. Você tem que ler a documentação para saber.

Ou seja, a decisão é do desenvolvedor do código. E isto provavelmente está na documentação indicando se você pode ou deve usar um `catch` para capturar a exceção gerada por alguma API que você está usando, ainda que não esteja de forma tão clara.

O PHP tem algumas APIs que você pode escolher como o erro será gerado. Mas isto não é o padrão de todas as APIs e provavelmente você não criará esta opção no seu código.

Comment: eu fato eu posso escolher lançar um `throw`, contudo o que quero disser é quanto aos `Exceptions` padrões.

Comment: Isto não existe, a lista de hoje não é a mesma de amanhã. Não faria sentido ficar listando aqui. A função do mecanismo de exceção é justamente não precisar saber todas que existem. Se isto fosse importante o mecanismo seria outro muito mais simples. Você precisa saber o que usar naquele momento e isto varia de acordo com uma série de circunstâncias variáveis que não dá para colocar em uma resposta.